# what must be installed first for instapy to run without errors?

Tags: python, instapy

I created a instagram bot to search for hashtags, like the posts, comment and follow the accounts from the posts but it can't even get to the point of login into the account. I have Instapy and selenium installed but I keep running into errors concerning webdriver please help with how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Post the error output; difficult to figure out otherwise.